# Form data is undefined in Nest.JS - multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, upload, nestjs, multer

I'm trying to send formData from React app via upload file option (input field), but formData is empty on Nest.JS side.
The route has decorator based on multer, but the data is parsed as undefined.

```
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('excel'))
    uploadFile(
        @UploadedFile() excel: Express.Multer.File,
    ) {
        console.log(excel) // undefined;
    }
```

```
const file = event.target.files?.item(0);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('excel', file);
```

```
await axios.post(url, formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary="X-TEST-BOUNDARY"'}});
```

Works without problem from insomnia / postman calling only the service

BR, Igor

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we use axios without the headers and the file we catch like this:

```js
const file = event.target.files[0]
```

Comment: The issue was that multer expects axios to send formData as, data: formData, but I was creating custom object, like: {excel: formData}

Comment: @ИгорТашевски so what was the resolution buddgi?